# Why this constructor overloading can not work? (template and typedef occurs)

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2012, typedef, constructor-overloading

**I am using VS2012 as compiler.**

First there is a `typedef` due to the lack of `template aliasing`

```
template <typename T>
struct HvVector
{
    typedef std::vector<T> rt;
};
```

Then I want to instantiate object of this class:

```
class LetYouDo
{
public:
    template<typename CLASS, typename TYPE>
    LetYouDo(const std::string& name, TYPE (CLASS::*field))
    {
        std::cout << "3" << std::endl;
    }

    template<typename CLASS, typename TYPE>
    LetYouDo(const std::string& name, typename HvVector<TYPE>::rt (CLASS::*field), TYPE* p)
    {
        std::cout << "4" << std::endl;
    }        
};
```

With an example class like:

```
class Victim
{
public:
    int m1;
    HvVector<int>::rt m2;
};
```

So the real case is like:

```
Victim v;
v.m1 = 10;
v.m2.push_back(10);
LetYouDo o1("m1", &Victim::m1);
LetYouDo o2("m2", &Victim::m2, static_cast<int*>(0));
```

But the compiler gives an error:

```
error C2660: 'LetYouDo::LetYouDo' : function does not take 3 arguments
```

**So it looks like the compiler does not know my second constructor, why?**

The extra `TYPE* p` is an attempt to give the compiler my real type, because a `typedef` type like `HvVector<TYPE>::rt` can not deduce the template argument type unless I specify it clearly.

Edit:

Here's an online test code which works fine with `gcc 4.8.1`, so I think it's the problem of VS2012: [ideone.com/YawsaB](http://ideone.com/YawsaB)

Comment: Since this *is* a question-answer site, is it really necessary to state that you're looking for an answer? :-(

Comment: well, its just some pre-text for saying `thanks`...xD Could you please answer this question? Reeealy need some help!

Comment: No need, shorter is better... Anyway, can you post an mcve on a live compiler site?

Comment: You mean like this? http://ideone.com/YawsaB

Comment: Seems like this site's compiler can do it...but vs2012 can not

Comment: @KerrekSB Do you have any suggestion if I cant change my compiler? Mr. Kerrek?

Comment: No, since I don't have or know that compiler. Retag the question to make the compiler version explicit and wait till someone with expertise comes by, or contact the vendor...

Comment: Still [doesn't compile with vc++ 2013](http://rextester.com/OQSEC3673). And even [doesn't compile without overload with 2 parameters](http://rextester.com/YWUZG20800)! It looks like a very strange bug of vc++.

Comment: Replace `typename HvVector<TYPE>::rt ` by a deduce templata parameter and it will work. VC is confused by trying to deduce every template parameter type on its own. Your idea to put TYPE* p there was good, but not sufficient here. I can't tell if its a bug or within the behaviour allowed by the standard, but its definetly something that has annoyed many people writing heavy templated code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on the type deduction done by the constructors. You can make the types explicitly by making the class a template rather its constructors. This works:

```
template<typename CLASS, typename TYPE>
class LetYouDo
{
public:
    LetYouDo(const std::string& name, TYPE (CLASS::*field))
    {
        std::cout << "3" << std::endl;
    }

    LetYouDo(const std::string& name, typename HvVector<TYPE>::rt (CLASS::*field), TYPE* p)
    {
        std::cout << "4" << std::endl;
    }        
};

LetYouDo<Victim,int> o1("m1", &Victim::m1);
LetYouDo<Victim,int> o2("m2", &Victim::m2, static_cast<int*>(0));
```

If you transform the constructors into methods them you will see a proper message from the compiler. Try:

```
class LetYouDo
{

    template<typename CLASS, typename TYPE>
    void LetYouDoInit(const std::string& name, typename HvVector<TYPE>::rt (CLASS::*field), TYPE* p)
    {
        std::cout << "4" << std::endl;
    }        
};

LetYouDo o2;
o2.LetYouDoInit("m2", &Victim::m2, static_cast<int*>(0));
```

You will get:

```
1>c:\users\all\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1.cpp(47): error C2784: 'void LetYouDo::LetYouDoInit(const std::string &,HvVector<TYPE>::rt CLASS::* ,TYPE *)' : could not deduce template argument for 'HvVector<TYPE>::rt CLASS::* ' from 'std::vector<T,std::allocator<_Ty>> Victim::* '
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=int
1>  ,            _Ty=int
1>          ]
1>          c:\users\all\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1.cpp(24) : see declaration of 'LetYouDo::LetYouDoInit'
1>c:\users\all\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1.cpp(47): error C2780: 'void LetYouDo::LetYouDoInit(const std::string &,TYPE CLASS::* )' : expects 2 arguments - 3 provided
1>          c:\users\all\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1.cpp(18) : see declaration of 'LetYouDo::LetYouDoInit'
```

The message will go away if you make the types explicit:

```
LetYouDo o2;
o2.LetYouDoInit<Victim,int>("m2", &Victim::m2, static_cast<int*>(0));
```